# Why doesn this Theano.scan function not throw an error?

Tags: python, theano

I have this piece of code from the Theano documentation that calculates the polynomial

```
import numpy
import theano
import theano.tensor as T


theano.config.warn.subtensor_merge_bug = False

coefficients = theano.tensor.vector("coefficients")

x = T.scalar("x")

max_coefficients_supported = 1000
# Generate the components of the polynomial
full_range=theano.tensor.arange(max_coefficients_supported)

components, updates = theano.scan(fn=lambda coeff, power, free_var:
                                            coeff * (free_var ** power),
                                    outputs_info=None,
                                    sequences=[coefficients, full_range],
                                    non_sequences=x)

polynomial = components.sum()

calculate_polynomial = theano.function(inputs=[coefficients, x],
outputs=polynomial)

test_coeff = numpy.asarray([1, 0, 2], dtype=numpy.float32)
print calculate_polynomial(test_coeff, 3)
```

I think what it is doing is calculating 1*(3^0) + 0*(3^1) + 2*(3^2) which is 19.0 which is my output.

My question is that full_range is an array of [0, 1, 2, ... ,998, 999] containing 1000 elements. This is being used as sequences in the Theano scan parameter.

Why doesn't w.r.t the sequences parameter in the scan function. It has two sequences as input namely coefficients and full_range. This means that in every iteration of the scan function, it picks one value from each of these inputs and runs the code

```
coeff * (free_var ** power)
```

where the free_var is 3. How does the code manage to run successfully when the number of elements in coeff is just 3 while the number of elements in power (which is the full_range input) has 1000 elements? I am missing something here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When multiple sequences are passed to `scan`, it will iterate as many times as there are elements in the shortest sequence.

[The documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/scan.html#iterating-over-the-first-dimension-of-a-tensor-calculating-a-polynomial) says:

> given multiple sequences of uneven lengths, scan will truncate to the
>   shortest of them. This makes it safe to pass a very long arange, which
>   we need to do for generality, since arange must have its length
>   specified at creation time.